# Recursive HBM Mapping

Tags: hibernate, hbm

Can I do the following in my HBM mapping?

```
<class name="Employee" table="employees">
    <!-- assume that each person only has exactly one supervisor -->
    <many-to-one name="supervisor" class="Employee" column="supervisorId" />
</class>
```

When I use the above HBM mapping, my server refuses to start with the following error:

```
org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test object Employee
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at Employee.<init>(Employee.java:11)
at Employee.<init>(Employee.java:11)
at Employee.<init>(Employee.java:11)
...... (about a hundred duplicates)
```

line 11 of Employee.java merely says:

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {
```

How should I model my supervisor-employee relationship? There is no special POJO for supervisor and supervisor objects have no special fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate shouldn't have a problem with mapping such a relationship.

It looks like infinite recursion is caused by error in your code, something like this:

```
public class Employee {
    private Employee supervisor = new Employee();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I had that exact line of code. I changed it to private Employee supervisor = null and now it works.